# Justify main caption in figure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have two figures that I am putting vertically in my text. The two figures are located in the same column, on top of each other. I am trying to left justify the main caption of this figure (by default the caption is centered). But I am unsuccessful. Here is the text:

```
\documentclass[reprint,
superscriptaddress,showpacs,amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={0.92cm,0cm}}
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[height=7.3cm,width=8cm]{example-image}%
     }
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={1.2cm,0cm}}
        \hspace{-4mm} 
    \subfloat[]{%
        \includegraphics[height=3.8cm,width=8.3cm]{example-image}%
    }

   \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}             \caption{This is the main caption that I would like to have it justified and not centered (a) test figure 1 (b) test figure 2 } 
\label{figlabel} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

I had two figures with different scales so I had to have them with different sizes and shift (a) and (b) labels differently for each figure. But my problem is the main caption under the two figs. Even including

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
```

or

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
```

I wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just the document body!

Comment: When I compile your code, the subfigures are placed next to each other, rather than one below the other. Is this intended? If it's not, please modify the code appropriately.

Comment: Don't you need the caption package for \captionsetup?  And try not to use subfig if you can help it.  The subcaption package is generally preferred, but minipages and tabulars will also work.

Comment: The `revtex4-1` document class isn't really compatible with the `caption` package. (While you don't load `caption` directly, it is loaded by the `subfig` package in order to make use of the former package's `\captionsetup` macro.) The upshot is that the `\captionsetup` macro doesn't have much of an effect -- if any. `revtex4-1` captioning style is *center-set* the caption; assuming you're stuck with this document class, it may be a good idea to come to terms with this setting.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Mico Could that be an answer, perhaps?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Since you asked so nicely :-) ...

Answer (score 1):

The `revtex4-1` document class isn't really compatible with the `caption` package. While you don't load `caption` directly, it is loaded by the `subfig` package in order to make use of the former package's `\captionsetup` macro.

The upshot is that the `\captionsetup` macro doesn't have much of an effect -- if any. `revtex4-1` captioning style is to center-set the caption. Assuming you're forced to stick with this document class, it may be a good idea to come to terms with this stylistic setting.